# Spreadsheet function to sum all values in one column based on criteria from another column

Tags: google-sheets

I want a spreadsheet function that will produce a sum of all values in column B for when column A is equal to `X` and when it is equal to `Y`.

```
A     B

X    10
Y     3
X     7
X    22
Y     4
Y     9
```

The output should look like the following (where `39` and `16` are the results of the formulas):

```
X    39           -> 10 + 7 + 22
Y    16           -> 3 + 4 + 9
```

Comment: and yes, i am spreadsheet noob =)

Comment: Belongs on webapps.stackexchange

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this

```
X   10
Y   3
X   7
X   22
Y   4
Y   9

X   "=SUMIF(A1:A6;A8;B1:B6)"
Y   "=SUMIF(A1:A6;A9;B1:B6)"
```

Answer (score 6):

use `SUMIF(range, criteria, sum_range)`: (sum values between B2-B8, using value in A2-A8 as criterea, using the specified condition)

```
=SUMIF(A2:A8,"=X",B2:B8)
=SUMIF(A2:A8,"=Y",B2:B8)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to calculate the totals.  For the "X" values:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6="X")*(B1:B6))
```

for the "Y" values:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6="Y")*(B1:B6))
```

Hope that helps,

Eric Melski

**EDIT:**  Apparently you must use ARRAYFORMULA to use SUMPRODUCT in Google's spreadsheet.  See for example http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=13a3eb824446e891&hl=en

Comment: I believe it is supported, but you must use ARRAYFORMULA to use SUMPRODUCT.  See my edit above.

Comment: +1: In Excel 2003 I was able to do =SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6<>"")*(B1:B6)) to only count items in B1 through B6 where there was something in the corresponding A1 through A6.  Thanks for the answer (to my slightly different question)!

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty solution is to make two new columns.  For each row x, Cx should be something like =Ax=='X'?Bx:0.  Do the same for column D, but checking Ax=='Y'.  Then sum C and D.

(Not sure if that matches Google Spreadsheet syntax exactly.)

Comment: one reason I can't add more columns is because I'm building a google form and if I add columns it gets really crazy. I have to put this formula on a separate spreadsheet without modifying the spreadsheet that the google form is using.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
=query(A:B, "select A, sum(B) group by A order by sum(B) desc")
```

Comment: You should maybe add a little explanation to that.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Google Docs doesn't support the `sumproduct` and the `--` operator, as Excel does, is a bit bothering. You could always replicate the functionality using more columns, but as you responded in one of your comments, this seems impossible.

You could check if a hidden column is rendered in the form. If it is not, this is the way to go.