# Create column containing a list of words (unique) used in the sentences that appear in another column?

Tags: google-sheets

In my Google Sheets I have a column with sentences (one per row) like:

```
How is it going?
I am going to the store.
He is going to play baseball.
```

I want to create another column that would contain a unique list of words (one word per row, ignoring capitalization as if everything were lowercase), so a few rows of it might look like:

```
how
is
it
going
I
am
to
the
store
```

etc.

---

Also, as a bonus, I am looking to create ANOTHER column that would have the amount each of these words appeared. For example, it the first few rows might look like:

```
1
1
1
2
```

because `how`, `is`, and `it` appear once and `going` appears twice.

Comment: You are asking the stack overflow community to write a script for you without showing evidence of what you have found out for yourself. I'm new here, but I bet that is why it was down voted. In answer to your question have you tried using formulas in the spreadsheet to do this?

Comment: I was looking stuff up about formulas, but it wasn't clear to me what a good solution would be.

While I was searching Stack Overflow to see if this question had been asked before, I found questions that seemed sort of similar (sort of like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703325/what-would-be-the-spreadsheet-function-to-sum-all-values-in-one-column-based-on?rq=1) that didn't indicate anything about what the asker had already tried, so I was just confused why some would get many up-votes and this one got down-voted.

Comment: I think the question has sense because the task can be also solved with formulas. And besides the question could be behelpful for the other users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

I wrote a custom function to break up the sentences into words, remove punctuation etc. You'd add this under TOOLS>SCRIPT EDITOR

```
function WORDS(input) {
  var input = input.toString();
  var inputSplit = input.split(" ");
  Logger.log(inputSplit);
  inputSplit = inputSplit.toString();

  var punctuationless = inputSplit.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\?^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g," ");
  var finalString = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
  finalString = finalString.toLowerCase();
  return finalString.split(" ") ;
}
```

Once you've done that and saved it, you can then use it like so `=WORDS(A1:A3)`

From there I just used the Google Functions available.

`=unique(c2:c)` gives us the unique words in the list
`=COUNTIF(C2:C,"="&D2)` then counts occurrences of the words

There's a working example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJbFvldjkgIKDv7Cwouz7gXMslk79G-fhkVQerKmB_o/edit#gid=0)

I'm not sure how well it'd behave at large scale but it could set to deal with smaller ranges.

Answer (score 6):

Ussume, the list is in column A.

Paste this formula in cell C2:

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",A:A)," "),"\w+")))
```

This will give the list of all words.

And then paste this formula in any free cell:

```
=QUERY({C:C,C:C},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1",1)
```

The result is:

[image]

Single formula solution is also possible:

```
=QUERY({{"Words";ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",A:A)," "),"\w+")))},{"Words";ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",A:A)," "),"\w+")))}},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1",1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied Tom Woodward's script and added a line that removes single letter words from the output.

`var noSingleLetterWords = punctuationless.replace(/\b[a-zA-Z]{1}\b/g,"");`

This is the end result.

```
function WORDS(input) {
    var input = input.toString();
    var inputSplit = input.split(" ");
    Logger.log(inputSplit);
    inputSplit = inputSplit.toString();

    var punctuationless = inputSplit.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\?^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g," ");
    var noSingleLetterWords = punctuationless.replace(/\b[a-zA-Z]{1}\b/g,"");
    var finalString = noSingleLetterWords.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
    finalString = finalString.toLowerCase();
    return finalString.split(" ") ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly longer than [@Max Makhrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5372400/max-makhrov)'s excellent [A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39869422/1505120) but case insensitive (so that, for example, `He` and `he` are not counted separately in a sentence such as `He said he would.`) and numbers (eg `711` in, for example, `I am going to the 711 store.`) don't give rise to errors:

```
=unique(ArrayFormula(lower(TRANSPOSE(split(join(" ",left(A1:A3,len(A1:A3)-1))," ")))))
```

On the other hand, does count separately `is` and `"is"` in, for example `How is "is" going?`.

For the QUERY I would have added a sort, either alphabetically:

```
=QUERY({C:C,C:C},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 order by Col1",1)
```

or by frequency:

```
=QUERY({C:C,C:C},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc",1)
```

Though perhaps what was required was merely:

```
=countif(B:B,B1)
```

copied down to suit (assuming individual words are in ColumnB, starting in Row1), say from a formula such as:

```
=ArrayFormula(lower(TRANSPOSE(split(join(" ",left(A1:A3,len(A1:A3)-1))," "))))
```